# FIWARE - Orion and STH duplicated notifications

Tags: notifications, duplicates, fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-sth-comet

I have a scenario where two or more subscriptions were made to some entity (with the same notification url). In this case, I have many of the same subscriptions. When the attributes related to subscriptions conditions are updated, I have as many notifications as subscriptions I made. This way, I have unnecessary messages, resulting in unnecessary processing.

Is there a way to deal with this? Both Orion and STH Comet do not handle with this. Maybe Orion and STH can deny the creation of a subscription that already exists. If this Orion behavior is updated, maybe STH Comet does not need to handle that.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue that has been raised many times, but not fixed yet. It is very easy to create duplicated subscriptions, by mistake for instance, that notify multiple times confusing the notified service ...

Comment: Actually, there is an issue in the Orion github repository related with this (not exactly about denying but updating, but very close): https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1117. If you want to support the need of that feature, please add a +1 at github

Comment: Is the issue still actual? It's there any way to prevent duplication?